# Estimating Value of $f'(x)$ given values of $f(x)$

Tags: functions

I was doing an exercise online and I was stuck on a few questions , if you could help me answer these type of question, I can get the hang of doing them.. its an online course so I haven't learnt a lot..

These are the 2 questions that I got stuck on:

> > 2) The function $f$ is continuous on the interval $[3,13]$ with selected values of $x$ and $f(x)$ given in the table. Use the data to approximate $f'(3.5)$
> >
> > [image]
> >
> > 3) $f$ is a differentiable function on the interval $[0,1]$ and $g(x) = f(3x) $. The table below gives values of $f'(x)$. What is the value of g'(0.1)?
> >
> > [image]

I have no clue what to do for  2 but for 3 i was thinking that the answer would be $3$..

Any help will be appreciated and apologies for the tables in picture format I couldn't find a way to do them in mathjax..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 2): $f'(3.5)$ is the slope of $f$ at the point $x=3.5$, but the data doesn't tell us what $f'(3.5)$ is. One good approximation is to take the average slope between $3$ and $4$, ie. $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\frac{f(4)-f(3)}{4-3}=6$

For 3): If $g(x)=f(3x)$, then $g'(x)=f'(3x)\cdot 3$ (don't forget chain rule!), so when $x=0.1$, then $g'(0.1) = f'(0.3)\cdot 3 = 9$.

Comment: Just as a comparison if we instead use a qubic spline through the data points we get $f'(3.5) = 5.94$. Computing this is much more work and given the large spacing to the next point ($4 \to 7$) the linear approximation as you have done here should be more than good enough.